# get second item by id

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation

On a SharePoint landing page I have several CQWP that place an ID multiple times in the DOM. I want to access the second and only the second ID called hiddenArea.

I can't change the control in any fashion and I need to use javascript code below modified with the fix as a solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("My Assignments");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "My Assignments";
a.href = "/ourcompany/departments/insretsol/grpptr/Lists/TDM%20Select%20an%20Assignment/Applicant%20View.aspx";
a.className += "noContentLink"
document.body.appendChild(a);
document.getElementById('hiddenArea').appendChild(a);</script>
<style type="text/css">
.hiddenAreaContainer{
    /*padding:5px;*/
    display:inline-block !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
.noContentMsg{
    /*text-align:right !important;*/
}</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. getElementById will only return the first one (or one at least).

You may be able to use:

```
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#hiddenArea");
  // elems[1] has the 2nd one
```

Comment: I totally get that it is invalid HTML but we have no other options. Would you replace this document.getElementById('hiddenArea').appendChild(a); with this var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id='hiddenArea']"); ?

Comment: Note: I changed how I referenced the ID above - I think this will work also.

Comment: I think you can get away with just replacing the getElementById with:  document.querySelectorAll("#hiddenArea")[1].appendChild(a);  Of course this has no error checking, so it assumes there are always two elements with hiddenArea as the ID...